# Aggregrate character in R

Tags: r, char, int, aggregate

Hi I have a list of header at below:

```
> head(qu3)
        fips      SCC Pollutant Emissions  type year
114288 24510 10100601  PM25-PRI     6.532 POINT 1999

> str(qu3)
'data.frame':   2096 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ fips     : chr  
 $ SCC      : chr  
 $ Pollutant: chr  
 $ Emissions: num  
 $ type     : chr  
 $ year     : int
```

I try to use code to aggregate by year and it works:

```
qu3.aggreg <- aggregate(emission, by=list(year), sum)
```

But when I try to use the code below to aggregate the data with different column it doesn't work and shows the error of below for some reasons. I guess this maybe do with int and char ?

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  object 'type' not found

> qu3.aggreg <- aggregate(emission ~ type, data=qu3, FUN=SUM)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = emission ~ type, data = qu3) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'type')
> qu3.aggreg <- aggregate(emission, by=list(type ), sum)
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  object 'type' not found
```

Comment: I am not sure how your first code using year worked since you never specified the data frame name. Did you attach the data frame or had those two columns in the memory? I haven't used aggregate much but it doesn't make sense that it will be able to figure out which data frame you are talking about unless you specify. The error is exactly what I would expect since the object "type" doesn't exist in R's workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also can you check the variable names like is it emission or Emissions? I find Emissions on your str(qu3)

Answer (score 0):

First I agree on what  Rohit Das wrote.

If you get the last error the first code should not have worked as well.

You need to specify the data to use, so it should look like this:

```
qu2.aggreg <- aggregate(qu3$emission, by=list(qu3$year), sum)
```

The error for the line:

```
qu3.aggreg <- aggregate(emission ~ type, data=qu3, FUN=SUM)
```

Say, that the length differ, so might be that there are NA's in the column qu3$type.
Therefore try first:

```
qu3$type <- factor(qu3$type, exclude=NULL)
```

This makes `type` a factor, where the Missing values (NA's) are a level. 
Then:

```
  qu3.aggreg <- aggregate(emission ~ type, data=qu3, FUN=SUM)
```

Should work.

Comment: HI Benjamin, thanks for the quick reply. I have checked there is no NA value in the column of type. I have try your last code, and it still shows the same error!

> qu3.aggreg <- aggregate(emission ~ type, data = qu3,FUN =  sum)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = emission ~ type, data = qu3) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'type')

Comment: I think the error comes from the variable name "type" maybe there is blank space behind?

Comment: can you maybe add the result for summary(qu3) or more rows of your data to the query?